# Snake case json when using default Grails JSON renderer

Tags: json, grails, groovy, formatting

I am building an app with Groovy/Grails (long-time Java developer), and have had some difficulty with making the JSON renderer do what I want. I would like to change the default name rendering scheme to snake case instead of camel case.

The controller code is very simple right now:

```
Fund show(String id) {
  respond fundService.getFund(id)
}
```

With Java I would use Jackson and a custom naming strategy, like so:

```
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

Any help would be appreciated! If there is no way of doing this, and I just need to switch out the renderer wholesale, I would welcome knowing that as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom marshaller - you can control anything from there

see here how to create one:

http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/

Comment: That worked, thank you! For anyone else looking, named configs are also an option: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/07/grails-goodness-using-converter-named.html